# Conditional compilation failed

Tags: compiling, programming

I think you can understand the scenario of the following code only by reading it.

```
% compile with pdflatex -shell-escape

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{filename.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifsecret
\begin{document}
common 1

\ifsecret
I have a top secret message here.
\fi

common 2
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=secret-incuded "\AtBeginDocument{\secrettrue} \input{filename}"}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=secret-excluded "\AtBeginDocument{\secretfalse} \input{filename}"}
Done, secret-included.pdf and secret-excluded.pdf have been generated!
\end{document}
```

What is wrong in my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\write` expands its contents. You don't want to expand `\AtBeginDocument`, do you?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mozartsecretfile.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifsecret
\begin{document}
common 1

\ifsecret
I have a top secret message here.
\fi

common 2
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=mozartsecretincluded
  \unexpanded{"\AtBeginDocument{\secrettrue} \input{mozartsecretfile}"}}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname=mozartsecretexcluded
  \unexpanded{"\AtBeginDocument{\secretfalse} \input{mozartsecretfile}"}}
Done, secret-included.pdf and secret-excluded.pdf have been generated!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh. It has been explained long time ago. Thank  you!